# How to remove white space in VB.Net

Tags: sql, vb.net

In the following code SqlDataReader 'dr' does not read the "SubjectCode" of subjects whose names contain white space; example English Language, Social Studies, Principles of Cost Accounting, etc. from the subjects table.

I'd therefore be more than grateful if someone could very kindly help me out immediately.

```vb
cmd = New SqlCommand( _
    "select subjectCode from ProgramDetails.subjects where subjectname='" & _
    Trim(subname) & " ' ", cn)
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
If dr.Read Then
    subcode = dr(0)
End If
dr.Close()
```

Comment: Your code is open to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) - you should be using parameterized queries instead of concatenating SQL.

Comment: You have a white-space at the end, is this desired? `" ' "`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You're open for [SQL-Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), use `SQL-Parameters`
2. You have a white-space at the end, i assume that this is not desired
3. You might want to use `LIKE` with the wildcard `%` instead:

For example:

```vb
Dim sql = "Select subjectCode From ProgramDetails.subjects where subjectname Like @subname"
Using con = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    Using cmd = New SqlCommand(sql, con)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subname", String.Format("%{0}%", "english"))
        Con.Open()
        Using rd = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            While rd.Read()  
                Dim subjectCode = rd.GetString(0)
                ' ... '
            End While
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: I've tried using your solution but I'm getting an error message "The connectionString has not been intialized" How do I go about resolving this issue? Thanks so much.

Comment: @Akaglo: `connectionsString` is just a string-variable which should be replaced with your real connection-string.

Comment: Well, you must put a valid connection string into `connectionString`. Something like `connectionString = "Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;"`. See [Connection strings for SQL Server 2005](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005#sqlconnection). This domain has useful information for all types of DBs.

Comment: Pls having followed your your suggestion your code executed successfully but it could not read the subjectCodes of subjects whose names have white space.

Comment: @Akaglo: Can you provide one or two examples?

Comment: The point is that the SubjectCode in the program is of type Integer  so I replaced GetString with GetInt32;hence, your code is only able to read subject codes of subject names without white space, example Biology, Chemistry, Physics,etc, but doesn't read SubjectCodes of subject names with white space, example English Language, Principles of Cost Accounting, etc. Pls I'm anxiously waiting for the solution.

Comment: @Akaglo: I don't see how the type of `subjectCode` is related to your problem. The point is that i'm using sql similar to(e.g.) `... WHERE subjectname LIKE '%English%'`. That would find `English` as well as `English Language` or `Language-English` since i'm using the wildcard `%`. Have a look: [**LIKE in T-SQL**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx).

Comment: @Akaglo: Here's a [**SQL-Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/faab3/4/0) to prove my words.

Comment: Strictly following your example, now it's only the subject code of English language that's being read, as indicated in line 4 of your coding. In that line of your coding, when I replace "english" with "social" it's only the subject code of Social Studies that's accordingly read. How can I make it read any subject code that's supposed to read at a time? This is because, in my program the subject Code is to be read into the variable "SubjectCode" before it saved into the table of that particular subject. (I've a table for each subject)

Comment: I mean the following line of code makes the SQLDataReader _rd_ becomes limited to reading only the subject code of English language: `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subname", String.Format("%{0}%", "english"))`. Pls show me how to make it read **any subjectCode**

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [RTRIM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178660.aspx)

```vb
cmd = New SqlCommand("select RTRIM(subjectCode) from ProgramDetails.subjects " + _
                     "where subjectname Like '" & Trim(subname) & "%'", cn)
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
If dr.Read Then
    subcode = dr(0)
End If
dr.Close()
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I've tried your solution but the problem still remains same; that is, only subjectCodes of subjects whose names are without white space is read by the SQLDataReader "dr"

Comment: try it again, please take note that, this query is prone of sql injection :)

Comment: I've just tried it again several times but it works the same way as the one you suggested previously. Please give me a different suggestion. thanks in advance.

Comment: I mean your edited code still reads subjectCodes of subjects whose names don't contain white space. Pls help me out.